# How to allow only a number (digits and decimal point and negative) to be typed in an input type 'number'?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was trying to use this [directive](https://github.com/kanishkpuri87/Angularjs-Directive-Accept-Positive-Negative-Decimal-Number-Only)
and it is working fine,

usage on input type text:

```
    <input valid-number ng-model="mynumber"
        allow-decimal="false" allow-negative="true" type="text" />
```

But when i try to use like the following,

usgae on input type number:

```
    <input valid-number ng-model="mynumber"
        allow-decimal="false" allow-negative="true" type="number" />
```

It's broken. i'm using input type number for mobile to open up the numeric keyboard.

Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the directive for input[type="number"]? AngularJS does that sort of validation itself. [Check the documentation for more information](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).

Comment: To restrict the dash/dot only once, instead of showing message restrict the user from entering dash/dot multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

From your plugin

[Angularjs-Directive-Accept-Positive-Negative-Decimal-Number-Only](https://github.com/kanishkpuri87/Angularjs-Directive-Accept-Positive-Negative-Decimal-Number-Only)

When you changed type from text to number, the error should be thrown for the default value

> Expected `0` to be a number

You need to replace this line in the plugin

```
if (text == '0' || text == null && attrs.allowDecimal == "false") return '0';
```

with

```
if (text == '0' || text == null && attrs.allowDecimal == "false") return 0;
```

Result:

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jcW3LLYcViznh5ZdTJeE?p=preview)